# Do I need to isolate the power to buzzer circuit from other sensitive circuit?

Tags: audio, signal-integrity, piezo-buzzer

I am planning to add a buzzer circuit, which will share the power plane with a micro-controller.  Do I need to add a choke or so to isolate the two components?  If so, how should I do it?  Thanks in advance.

Buzzer: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/CT-1205C-SMT-TR/102-1200-2-ND/504821

Answer (score 1):

No need for chokes or a separate power plane. Chokes generally don't do much at audio frequencies. Do use a supply decoupling capacitor, 10 uF or more should be enough.

That buzzer can take 30 mA, too much for most Microcontrollers so use a transistor like shown here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Does the 10uF decoupling cap be placed close to the buzzer or microcontroller?

Comment: Close to the microcontroller so that it gets the decoupled voltage. It is not so critical at these low (audio) frequencies. Don't worry too much about it :-)

Comment: Regarding the above circuit, you should add a large decoupling cap between the 5V supply at the buzzer and the ground at the emitter of the transistor and also make sure the wire connecting the emitter to ground runs back to right next to the neg term of the uC decoupling cap.

Answer (score 0):

You need separate grounds. Specifically, make sure the ground of the buzzer runs all the way back to the capacitor of the power supply. The important thing is that you don't want the ground current of the buzzer to mess with the other circuitry. Believe it or not, just moving the point at which the ground connects can make a huge difference because a wire actually has some resistance and inductance.

If you cannot move the ground connection, another possible fix would be to put a big capacitor right next to the ground end of the buzzer and then connect the positive terminal of the cap to the supply. This way the ground noise of the buzzer will go into the cap instead of the wire running back to the power supply.